# When viewing a badge page, show whether or not you currently have it

Tags: feature-request, badges, information-display

When viewing a badge's page (e.g. [Strunk and White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white)), it would be fantastic if it displayed on that page whether or not you currently had it.

As I was looking at the 2013 Moderator Election, I noticed the list of badges that are required for someone to nominate themselves. Each of them link to their own page, but for me to determine if I have the badge, I have to go do some digging into my own profile. It would be super convenient if it just showed that information right on the page.

```
 ( o Strunk & White )   Edit 80 posts.

 You have earned this badge.
```

Comment: We've got a total badge page redesign on the list, but it keeps getting bumped for more important things. I hope to get to it in the next few months.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Looking forward to that even if it's been bumped!

Comment: @JeremyTunnell so doesn't it justify [meta-tag:status-planned] for this question? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd To me, status-planned means that I've committed to fixing this specific problem, and the fix is imminent.  In this case, I haven't started thinking about the badge page redesign, so I can't guarantee that I'm going to fix this specific problem. Nor can I guarantee that it's going to be imminent. I'm afraid a "hey man, I feel your pain" is about all I'm willing to commit to at the moment :)

Comment: @Jeremy OK fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say this is a great idea. I'd go a step further too - It would be even better if they put your progress towards all your badges (on the badges page). Whilst I'm not against clicking individual badges and finding out more, it would prove useful and save time (the shortest of commodities) for all users to get an overview of their overall badge progress:

[image]

If we polled them, I'm sure users would be interested in seeing their badge progress **in one place**!

In addition to the obvious advantages (and having spent some time on MSO), I also think that this type of summary page would **decrease** the number and frequency of "*badge progress*" questions/answers/dupes/closures.

Comment: While I think showing a progress bar is a good idea, I think putting it all on one page like this might make it look a little too cluttered...  Just my opinion.

Comment: There could be a show-hide option (default to hide) for the progress meter if the page feels too crowded. Optionally, the meter could be shown per-badge on hover, or we could get someone to design a way to integrate the meter into the badge itself (behind the text, perhaps).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Agreed. Various ways of achieving it really, which will hopefully be the focus of the UI/UX at SE in getting this feature **status-completed**

Answer (score 26):

This is a good idea, and would be even better if they put your progress towards that badge on that page if you haven't earned it yet.  For example, there is no way to check your progress towards the Archaeologist badge.

```
 ( o Strunk & White )   Edit 80 posts.
```

[image: 35 to 80 progress line]

Comment: Ooooh, I love the idea of having the progress on that page as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have to say this. **`45`** of `80` should have the green bar at least past the half mark.

Comment: @Siva, good catch, back to the editing box for me.

Comment: Definitely this would be very useful!

Comment: @LanceRoberts A great no-brainer here. I'll dispair if we don't get a one-page badge summary. Just think of all the bandwidth we'd save!